# Email address lookup

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

Existing registrant should not be able to proceed when clicking 'ENTER' and have the following error message (in red) display below the Email Address field:
Oops! This email address has already entered the competition.
 can u guide me on this requiremnet

Comment: Hello @shiva D N! Welcome to SFSE, can you please provide some more info, including use case, good faith attempts you have used and any current code you have for your question. See here for advice on how to ask a question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6):

Taking a stab in the dark and assuming this is hosted on a cloud page, here is what I would do:

1. Have the page post to itself
2. Have a [lookup inside AMPScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm) to see if the emailaddress already exists in your DE
3. Have a [conditional](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm) to display error text if already exists or to do an AMPScript insert if it does not and display success content.

To post to itself:

`<form action="yourCloudPageURL" >`

Example Lookup:

```
%%[
   /* Assuming the input name is 'EmailAddress'
      This will pull the input value into AMPScript */
   SET @EmailAddress = RequestParameter("EmailAddress")

   /* This will check to see if the email address exists in DE */
   SET @Lookup = LOOKUPROWS('yourDE', 'EmailAddress", @EmailAddress)

]%%
```

Example Conditional:

```
%%[ IF ROWCOUNT(@Lookup) == 1 THEN 

   InsertData('yourDE','EmailAddress',@EmailAddress)

]%%

   <p style="color:green">Thank you for entering our competition!</p>

%%[ ELSE ]%%

   <p style="color:red">Oops! This email address has already entered the competition.</p>

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

You can also use this conditional logic to show/hide the form after submission to help prevent accidental double submissions.

Please be aware this would require a full form submission and a page refresh on every entry as all the logic is on the server side. I recommend this over a client side Javascript solution as many of those can potentially open a security risk to your SFMC data.